# ZINTERSTORE keep score of one set

Tags: redis

Am I correct that this is not possible with redis?

ZINTERSTORE two zsets (`A` and `B`), and have the `output` set's score equal to zset `B`'s scores?

I think the only ways are `AGGREGATE SUM|MIN|MAX`, so I don't think my use case can be done. Set `A`'s score is not predictable so can't just subtract the two.

`ZINTERSTORE out 2 setA setB` returns scores of `0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ZINTERSTORE's  `WEIGHTS` option to give setA weight of 0 and 1 for setB:

```
ZINTERSTORE out 2 setA setB WEIGHTS 0 1
```

This will multiply A's scores by 0 and keep B's scores as is.